How do I properly incorporate text from a .txt file in angular?
For a college project ive been trying to build a website with angular.
Said website will incorporate a lot of text, which is why i thought it might be a good idea to get that text from a txt file instead of writing everything into the html file.
After asking Chat Gpt and googling a bit I ended up with the code below, consisting of one parent and child ts file. However no matter what i do i cant get past an error saying: "TS2339: Property 'getTexts' does not exist on type 'TextService'", even though TextService is defined in text.service.ts.
After some more searching i found a few similar problems that all got solved by implementing httpclient differently than i did. After doing it through main.ts I got only more error messages though. What am I doing wrong or is my whole approach just bad?

    text.service.ts

    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

    @Injectable({
       providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class TextService {
      private url = 'assets/activeTexts.txt';

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

      getTexts(): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get<any>(this.url);
      }
    }

    app.component.ts

    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
    import { NavComponent } from './components/nav/nav.component';
    import { TextService } from './text.service';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
 
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      standalone: true,
      imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, HttpClientModule, NavComponent],
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrl: './app.component.css'
    })


    export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
      title = 'Usage';
      stromVerbrauch: number = 8;
      buttonStates: boolean[] = [false, false, false, false, false]; // Zustand der Knöpfe
      buttonTexts: string[] = ['Button 1', 'Button 2', 'Button 3', 'Button 4', 'Button 5'];
      lastActivatedButtonIndex: number | null = null; // Index des zuletzt aktivierten Knopfes

      longText1: string = '';
      longText2: string = '';

      constructor(private textService: TextService) {}

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.loadTexts();
      }

      loadTexts(): void {
        this.textService.getTexts().subscribe({
          next: data => {
            this.longText1 = data.text1;
            this.longText2 = data.text2;
          },
          error: err => {
            console.error('Error fetching texts:', err);
          }
        });
      }




please share the issue replicated on stackblitz, for now try using provideHttpClient() inside the providers array of bootstrapApplication, code samples available online for this.

The easiest way for you to debug the problem is to use the debugger keyword directly in the component's constructor and check what is textService in the DevTools.

Can you better quantify the amount of text you're planning to show? How much of that text is going to be richly formatted? It's probably not a real problem to just implement the text in HTML.

oh, i wanted to use about 3000signs for my text. Would that still be worth it for straight up html implementation?

hmmm i already tried using 'provdeHttpClient()' into my main.ts file but it didnt seem to do anything. How would an example for that look like and will i need to change anything in my app.component.ts according to that? Regarding the stackblitz one, ill do my best to replicate it, however im kinda new to this stuff so im not quite sure how long it might take!

Even with the debugger on i still get the same Error: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_AppComponent])[_HttpClient -> _HttpClient -> _HttpClient]:    NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient! it seems to me that import of httpclient is not properly working for me. My main.ts file looks like this: `import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
providers: [provideHttpClient()]
})
.catch(err => console.error(err))`

@HarryBudder First of all, next time please add the error and stacktrace to the question to make it easier to investigate your issue. Secondly, debugger was needed to investigate a value that you receive instead of your textService (null, undefined or something else), not to solve the problem. Have you managed to find a solution? If not, can you create a small demo app to reproduce the issue?
